# How to get a value of variable from another form in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, parameter-passing

I have 2 forms. Form 1 is mainForm and form 2 is WordSearch. I want to pass the value of newSystemRec from WrodSearch to mainForm. My both forms have access to datalayer.cs file. From where I get my newSystemRec vale in WordSearch form.
this is my WordSearch code:

```
public enum Category { Schematic, Component }

public partial class WordSearch : Form
{
    private DataLayer dataLayer;
    private MainForm mainForm;
    public event EventHandler<JumpToEventArgs> JumpTo;
    public event EventHandler ModeChanged;
    public event EventHandler SystemChanged;
    public event EventHandler<SimEventArgs> SimChanged;
    private SystemMode systemMode;
    private p2p p2pMode, originalMode;
    private Int32 systemRec;
    private string fileName;
    public Int32 projectRec { get; set; }

    public WordSearch(Category category, String title)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.dgSearch.Style.VerticalAlignment = C1.Win.C1TrueDBGrid.AlignVertEnum.Center;
        this.Icon = Properties.Resources.TDXm;
        if (category == Category.Schematic)
            SetDefaultCategory(true, false);
        else
            SetDefaultCategory(false, true);            
        dataLayer = new DataLayer(false);
        rbRefDes.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.rb_CheckedChanged);
        rbComp.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.rb_CheckedChanged);
        rbSchematic.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.rb_CheckedChanged);
        rdoTrace.Click += new EventHandler(this.rbTraceAndSim);
        rdoSim.Click += new EventHandler(this.rbTraceAndSim);
        lblModel.Text = title;
    }

    private void WordSearch_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (fileName == null) return;
        if (originalMode != p2pMode)
        {
            if (ModeChanged != null)
                ModeChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
        //Need to pass the value below
        Int32 newSystemRec = dataLayer.GetSystemType(fileName, p2pMode);
        if (systemRec != newSystemRec)
        {
            if (SystemChanged != null)
                SystemChanged(null, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
```

and this is my mainForm:

```
    public Int32 newSystemRec { get; set; }

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();           
        InitializeP2Trace();           
        dataLayer.InsertHandler(this.Handle);
        Args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
        MethodInvoker mi = new MethodInvoker(EmsJump);
        this.dgComp.Style.VerticalAlignment = C1.Win.C1TrueDBGrid.AlignVertEnum.Center;
        this.dgSchematic.Style.VerticalAlignment = C1.Win.C1TrueDBGrid.AlignVertEnum.Center;
        dgSchematic.Splits[0].ColumnCaptionHeight = 28;
        dgComp.Splits[0].ColumnCaptionHeight = 28;
        xmlPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "temp.xml");
        tsMarkup.Location = new Point(355, 0);
        if (Args != null)
            mi.Invoke();
    }

    private void wordSearch_SystemChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //How to get the value of newSystemRec???
        Int32 newSystemRec = 
        newSystemRec--;
        Int32 index = newSystemRec;
        switch (index)
        {
            case 1:
                systemMode = SystemMode.Hydraulic;
                cbSystem.SelectedIndex = 1;
                break;
            case 0:
            default:
                systemMode = SystemMode.Electrical;
                cbSystem.SelectedIndex = 0;
                break;
        }
        if (p2pMode == p2p.Trace)
            tabP2Trace.TabVisible = true;
    }
```

Comment: What would help here is to know how you instantiate your forms. From there it will be easier to provide assistance.

Comment: I now see where `mainForm` is declared but not where it is instantiated and shown.

Comment: I should also mention I'm not quite sure I understand your design. If `mainForm` is a member of `WordSearch` exactly what should happen when the latter is closed? Is `mainForm` supposed to outlive it's containing form?

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't show how the two forms are instantiated, but basically what you could do is exposing the value as a form's property and access it from your other form. Of course in order to do that there has to be a context in which both form instances are known so that one can access the other:

```
public int NewSystemRec
{
    get
    {
        // return value here
    }
}
```

Comment: If you would like to request further clarification from a post's author you should post a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Servy I actually have at least a part of the answer: exposing the value as a form property. I believe this is helpful enough to be an attempt to answer. As for the last paragraph I now moved it to the comments section.

Comment: -I added the part where it shows how my forms are instantiate together

Comment: However it's a very low quality answer, due to the complete lack of detail.  This is of course obvious, due to the lack of information in the question.  When a question is lacking information you should ask clarifying questions and strive to improve the question until it becomes possible to provide complete and high quality answers, rather than posting very vague, incompletely, low quality answers.

Comment: @Servy I respect your opinion, but mine is that a short, straight to the point answer can *still* be helpful. Besides, as stated in SO's help: downvoting should be done for useless and possibly dangerous advices. I don't think this answer, as "low quality" as you believe it is, qualifies for either of those. If it did then so would a large number of answers out there. :)

Comment: @user603948 the code you added does not provide clues at how your forms are instantiated and in which scope they belong.

Comment: @Crono Yes, there *are* a lot of low quality answers out there.  They should be downvoted.  We want to encourage quality answers on this site, and downvoting low quality answers is how we do that.  It's a shame that most people don't downvote nearly as much as they really should, and that so many people are willing to upvote posts that are not actually of high quality.  We'd have much better answers if they did.

Comment: @Servy I do not completely agree. The fact that an answer may not be as complete as it could be doesn't make it *automatically* useless. Sometimes it's more than enough to orientate the OP in the right direction and ultimately make him/her solve the problem, which is the whole point. That aside, there's a dedicated flag for low quality answers that much better suits that purpose. It doesn't punish the person who was willing to help (for free, should we all be reminded) *and* it doesn't cost rep points to the person who raises it either.

Comment: @Crono Flagging an answer a Very Low Quality means that the answer is so completely appalling that you feel it needs to be deleted.  It's for answers that are *so bad* that just downvoting isn't enough, they need to be erased from the face of the earth because they're just that useless.  Your answer isn't quite that bad, it is sufficient to simply decrease its score somewhat so that it is clearer to other readers that it is not a high quality answer.  Yes, you want to help, for free.  That's great.  That doesn't mean that if you post a low quality answer it'll get positive feedback.

Comment: @Servy You are free to downvote what you think are incomplete or low quality answers if you want. I for one prefer to keep my downvotes for posts that are *actual* bad advices. I let the OP decide whether or not an answer, as short and "low quality" as it seems, is helpful or not. If I feel an answer only lacks details I'll comment or add an answer of my own. That, IMHO, is a much better way to augment the overall quality of SO content. :)

Comment: @Crono Sure, and as much as I would like to, I cannot stop you from encouraging users to post low quality posts that don't answer questions, solve problems, and that are extremely lacking in detail.  There is lots of evidence that this is harmful, but it seems you don't care.  The best I can do is provide feedback on what low quality posts I come across, as I've done here.

Comment: @Servy At this point I don't think it's worth saying anything else. If you're this confident about me behaving carelessly and encouraging the degradation of SO's content quality, I suggest that you flag my answer to moderators. Have a nice day.

Comment: @Servy I am new to all this coding, please don't argue with each other cause this is not useful. I tried to provide more info.

Comment: @Crono I am new to all this coding, please don't argue with each other cause this is not useful. I tried to provide more info

Answer (score 0):

You can create a property on WordSearch like :

```
private int newSystemRec;
```

And access it with a Property :

```
public int NewSystemRec
{
    get
    {
        this.newSystemRec;
    }
}
```

exemple :

```
MainForm mainForm = new mainForm()
someControlOnForm1.Text = mainForm.NewSystemRec;
```

You can also use constructor :

```
public MainForm(int newSystemRecFromWordSearch ) {
 int newSystemRec = id;
}
```

and use it on WordSearch

```
var form = new MainForm(newSystemRec);
```

Hope it helps !